# Can I define my variables *inside* a function?

Tags: python, function, variables

Recently, I came across a beginner's question while self-teaching which asked for me to write a program to compute pay given input for hours worked and hourly rate. For any hours over 40, time-and-a-half should be paid. I did this successfully, but it seemed weird to me for some reason. The following code works perfectly and I got a 100% on the assignment:

```
def computepay(h,r):
    try:
        hrsfloat = float(h)
    except:
        print("Error: 'Hours' must be a number")
        quit()
    try:
        ratefloat = float(r)
    except:
        print("Error: 'hourly rate in dollars' must be a number")
        quit()
    if hrsfloat <= 40:
        return(hrsfloat*ratefloat)
    else:
        x=hrsfloat-40
        return((1.5 * x + 40) * ratefloat)

h = input("Enter Hours:")
r = input("Enter hourly rate in dollars:")
p = computepay(h,r)
print('Pay', p)
```

But for some reason I would much rather put the

```
 h = input("Enter Hours:")
 r = input("Enter hourly rate in dollars:")
```

inside the definition of `computepay` in the following manner:

```
def computepay(h,r):
    h = input("Enter Hours:")
    r = input("Enter hourly rate in dollars:")
    try:
        hrsfloat = float(h)
    except:
        print("Error: 'Hours' must be a number")
        quit()
    try:
        ratefloat = float(r)
    except:
        print("Error: 'hourly rate in dollars' must be a number")
        quit()
    if hrsfloat <= 40:
        return(hrsfloat*ratefloat)
    else:
        x=hrsfloat-40
        return((1.5 * x + 40) * ratefloat)

p = computepay(h,r)
print('Pay', p)
```

But this returns an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:[redacted]", line 20, in 
>     p = computepay(h,r)
>   NameError: name 'h' is not defined

So, is there a way to write `computepay` so that it is self-contained in this way? I don't know why I feel compelled to do this, but I really really do.

Comment: if you're printing `p`, that has to come from somewhere. So sure, you can put it inside your function, but then how is it going to get back out? (you could include it in your return, but that gets messy). So really what you'd probably want instead is a `def printPayFromInput(): ...` that houses the lines you currently have in global scope. That way it's still tidy, and you don't make `computepay` responsible for doing more than it needs to do, either.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that, if you never need to call `compute_pay` on values taken from somewhere else. If you do take the input from inside the function, there is no reason for `compute_pay` to take any parameters, though.

Comment: Simply remove the parameters `h, r`? Both in the function and the call to it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans oh, nifty idea! thanks!

Comment: @chepner, yes, I get that now, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. The problem, as the error message indicates, is that `h` and `r` don't exist at the point where you call the function:

```
p = computepay(h,r)
```

Note that these are *different* `h` and `r` from the ones defined inside the function! Read up on [scopes](https://pythonbasics.org/scope/) if you find this confusing.

The solution is to omit the arguments both from the function definition and from the call site:

```
def computepay():
    ...

p = computepay()
```

---

There is, however, a case to be made for passing these variables as arguments. It makes your function more versatile if it does one thing (computing the pay) rather than two orthogonal things (asking for input, then computing the pay). If you pass the values as arguments, the function doesn't care where they come from, so the calling code could read them from a file or from a GUI without having to modify the function itself.

This versatility also makes the function more amenable to unit testing, which Python supports particularly nicely in the form of [doctests](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/doctest.html).

If you're still getting to grips with the basics of the language, you shouldn't be concerned about this. I just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I think this is the solution I needed. The exercise specificed that it should take variables, which I why I didn't think of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify default values of `None` to determine if user input is necessary:

```
def computepay(h=None, r=None):
    if h is None:
        h = input("Enter Hours:")
    if r is None:
        r = input("Enter hourly rate in dollars:")
    try:
        hrsfloat = float(h)
    except:
        print("Error: 'Hours' must be a number")
        quit()
    try:
        ratefloat = float(r)
    except:
        print("Error: 'hourly rate in dollars' must be a number")
        quit()
    if hrsfloat <= 40:
        return(hrsfloat*ratefloat)
    else:
        x=hrsfloat-40
        return((1.5 * x + 40) * ratefloat)
```

Then you can call `computepay` in several different ways, including

```
p1 = computepay(40, 19)

p2 = computepay(40)  # Prompts for hours

p3 = computepay(r=19)  # Prompts for hourly rate

p4 = computepay()  # Prompts for hours and hourly rate
```

Comment: This is a nifty alternate solution, especially since the problem stubbornly required that I accept variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it would make most sense to keep the `computepay` function as it is: Taking some arguments, computing something from those arguments, and then returning the result. Then you can put all your code into a function which I have called `main` by convention here, which will then be invoked later:

```
def main():
    h = input("Enter Hours:")
    r = input("Enter hourly rate in dollars:")
    p = computepay(h,r)
    print('Pay', p)

main()
```